# Python regex negative lookahead on the FIRST instance of a word

Tags: python, regex

```
rex = r'today.*?monday (?!night)'
txt = 'today [blah blah] monday night but [blah blah] monday morning'
m = re.search(rex, txt)
```

This might only be possible in 2 stages but I'm only interested in the **first** instance of 'monday' so in this case I would want re.search() to return None. Instead of course it continues on to the second 'monday', finds it is not followed by 'night' and matches "today [blah blah] monday night but [blah blah] monday".

Comment: If you are interested in the first monday, you probably meant to use a positive lookahead and not a negative lookahead: `rex = r'today.*?monday (?=night)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this..

```
def search2lookahead(rex, txt, tag):
    m= re.search(rex,txt)
    if m !=None:
        if txt[m.end():].startswith(tag): return None
        else: return m.group()
    else: return None

rex = r'today.*?monday '
txt = 'today [blah blah] monday night but [blah blah] monday morning'
m = search2lookahead(rex,txt,"night")
print(m)
```